# Using events in Next js app router server component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

I am new to next js server components , and i am wondering what is the easiest way to use events like onClick. I have a list of posts that i receive from a getData function. Number 2 represent the number of posts that i want to list . I am wondering how can increment this value using a onClick event. I guess I should use a Button as client component. Do i have to use a PostList component as a client or something else ?

```
    export async function getData(category: string, numOfPosts: number) {
  const res = await getPostsByCategory(category, numOfPosts);

  if (!res) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return res;
}

const PostList = async ({ category }: { category: string }) => {
  const data = await getData(category, 2);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item: any, idx: number) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={idx}
            className={`${styles.grid2} ${categoryStyles.categoryPaddingBottom}`}
          >
            <Link href={`/${category}/${item.slug}`}>
              <div className={styles.relativeEle}>
                <Image
                  src={item.featuredImage.node.sourceUrl}
                  alt={item.title}
                  sizes="500px"
                  fill
                  priority={true}
                />
                <div className={styles.hoverOverlay}></div>
              </div>
            </Link>
            <div className={categoryStyles.flexCategory}>
              <Link href={`/${category}/${item.slug}`}>{item.title}</Link>
              <span>{item.date}</span>
              <div
                className={styles.dangerHtml}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html: item?.content.slice(0, 190) + " ...",
                }}
              ></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostList;
```

Comment: Make a separate component for `button` & make it client instead of making whole component client side.

Answer (score 2):

client-side interactions like onClick, onChange, etc., are not handled directly within server components. Server components are primarily intended to be used for rendering components on the server and fetching data to pre-render components before they are sent to the client.

If your component has events, that component should be a client component. These components are rendered on the client-side and interact directly with the user's browser environment. Think about it, how `onClick` event will work on the server. Events are handled by the browser